# Poetry throws .poetry/env: No such file or directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-poetry

I use Windows 10, python 3.9.7 and I tried to install poetry. I followed [this](https://gdevops.gitlab.io/tuto_python/distribution/packaging/poetry/installation/installation.html) tutorial. The installation process is good but then when I run `source $HOME/.poetry/env`, I get an error that says

> $HOME_PATH/.poetry/env: No such file or directory

I tried searching online but couldn't find a solution. What am I doing wrong and is there a way to fix this?

Comment: are you sure you run `source $HOME/.poetry/env` and not `source $HOME_PATH/.poetry/env` ?

Comment: Yes, I just didn't want to include my home path in the error.

Comment: So the path is valid and you don't have `.poetry` directory here? or you dont have `.poetry/env` file?

Comment: I don't have the `.poetry/env` file, unfortunately

Comment: if you don't have `.poetry/env` then maybe you should manually create empty file. OR maybe you should skip this part.

Answer (score 0):

The poetry installation guide has improved and can be accessed here: https://python-poetry.org/docs/#installing-with-the-official-installer

Those instructions have worked for me on Windows in the past

(Permalink to documentation source: https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/blob/128c528f392cd79b3f19f0dbf09b6e4c74809e2a/docs/_index.md#installation)